# Robotium - Chose an account in AccoutPicker with solo

Tags: java, android, testing, robotium

I call a new choose Accout Activity with:

```
Intent i = credencial.newChooseAccountIntent();
startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CHOOSE_ACCOUNT);
```

And now I want to test  my app with robotium. The first step is to choose an account int the choose account activity (account picker). How can I do that?